# How to avoid a specific pattern when using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a pattern like '2 years', '4 days' in a text, and meanwhile want to avoid a pattern like '2 years old', i.e., I don't want a 'old' following 'years'. I thought a negative lookahead (?!old) would help. But I don't know how to do it. I tried

> r=regex.compile(r'\b(\d+)\s*(years?|months?|days?)\s*(?!old)\b')

but it still match '2 years'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a full match you can omit the capture groups, and if there should be at least a single whitespace char between the words and the digits you can repeat 1 or more times using `\s+`

To prevent partial matches, you can use word boundaries `\b`

```
\b\d+\s+(?:year|month|day)s?\b(?!\s+old\b)
```

The pattern matches

- `\b\d+\s+` A word boundary, match 1+ digits and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?:year|month|day)s?\b` Match any of the alternatives and optional `s`
- `(?!\s+old\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not 1+whitespace chars followed by old and a word boundary to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/75JQHK/1)

Answer (score 1):

Put `\s*` inside the lookahead:

```
r'\b(\d+)\s*(years?|months?|days?)(?!\s*old)\b'
```

As far as I understand, your regexp matched `\s*` zero times for the `2 years old` case. The assertion fails since `2 years` ends at word boundary and the content after it is space followed by `old`.